# React: Invalid value for prop `savehere` on <div> tag. Either remove it from the element, or pass a string or number value to keep it in the DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, bootstrap-modal, react-bootstrap

I'm calling a parent method from child component using props and I'm getting this error:
[image]

The way I'm passing props to the AddGuest child component is like this:

```
import React from 'react';
 import globalService from '../services/globalService';

   import '../styles/chairqueue.css';
   import {buttonText,endPoint} from '../constants/global.constants';
   import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
   import ModalDialog from 'react-bootstrap/ModalDialog'
import ModalHeader from 'react-bootstrap/ModalHeader'
import ModalTitle from 'react-bootstrap/ModalTitle'
import ModalBody from 'react-bootstrap/ModalBody'
import ModalFooter from 'react-bootstrap/ModalFooter'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import  { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
import AddGuest from './addGuest'

class  CreateMeeting extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state={
      guestModalShow:false
    }
  }
  as=(a)=>{
    console.log('saasa')
    this.setState({guestModalShow:a});
  }
    asd=(a)=>{
    console.log(a) // works perfectly 

    }

    render(){

    return (

      <Modal
        {...this.props}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header >
        <label >Cancel</label>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            New Meeting
          </Modal.Title>
          <label>Create</label>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <h4><input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Meeting title"/></h4>
          {/* <DatePicker className="form-control"
        selected={startDate}
        onChange={setStartDate}
      /> */}
      <label variant="primary" onClick={()=>this.as(true)}>
            Add Guest 
          </label>

        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
        <AddGuest
        show={this.state.guestModalShow}
        savehere={(a)=>this.asd(a)}
        onHide={() => this.as(false)}

      />
      </Modal>      
    )
    }
  }
  export default CreateMeeting;
```

My child component is implemented as:

```
import React from 'react';

import '../styles/chairqueue.css';
import {buttonText,endPoint} from '../constants/global.constants';
import Modal from 'react-bootstrap/Modal'
import ModalDialog from 'react-bootstrap/ModalDialog'
import ModalHeader from 'react-bootstrap/ModalHeader'
import ModalTitle from 'react-bootstrap/ModalTitle'
import ModalBody from 'react-bootstrap/ModalBody'
import ModalFooter from 'react-bootstrap/ModalFooter'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button'
import  { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import DatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import "react-datepicker/dist/react-datepicker.css";
class  AddGuest extends React.Component  {
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state={
            startDate:new Date(),
            formControls: {
                email: '',
                name: ''

              },
        }
    }

      changeHandler = event => {
        const name = event.target.name;
        const value = event.target.value;

        this.setState({
          formControls: {
            ...this.state.formControls,
            [name]:
              value

          }
        });
      }
      sendData = () => {
          console.log('hhhh--')
        this.props.savehere("Hey Popsie, How’s it going?");
   }
      render(){
      return (
      <Modal  {...this.props} >
        <Modal.Header closeButton>
          <Modal.Title>Add Guest</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
        <h4><input type="text" name="name" value={this.state.formControls.name}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler} required className="form-control" placeholder="Guest Name"/></h4>
        <h4><input type="text" className="form-control" name="email" value={this.state.formControls.email}
                    onChange={this.changeHandler} required placeholder="Guest Email"/></h4>
        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button variant="secondary" onClick={this.props.onHide}>
            Close
          </Button>
          <Button variant="primary" onClick={()=>this.sendData()}>
            Save 
          </Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
      </Modal>
      );
      }
    }
    export default AddGuest;
```

Im using react boostrap modals and calling another modal. What could be problem causing this error?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The problem here is that a non-stardard input prop `savehere` of your `<AddGuest/>` component which is being directly spread into the `<Modal/>` component when `AddGuest` is rendered:

```
render(){
  return (
    <Modal  {...this.props} > {/*<-- This is problematic, as all props
                                  of AddGuest are spread into Modal
                                  including those not supported by 
                                  Modal such as "savehere"*/}
    ...
    </Modal>)
}
```

Rather than spread the props directly to `Modal`, consider [only applying the props](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/modal/#modal-props) that the `Modal` component supports. A simple solution for your case would be to explictly specify the `show` and `onHide` props passed to `AddGuest`:

```
render(){
  return (
  <Modal show={this.props.show} onHide={this.props.onHide}>
  ...
  </Modal>)
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This works, but I don't like it, I like being able to have `...props` spread in my component, just for the option to pass in whatever prop you want

Answer (score 6):

I also met this problem and solved it with Object Destructuring

```js
const {savehere, ...others} = props

return (
    <Modal ...others/>
)
```

use variable **savehere** to store the callback function, and use variable **other** to store the propertys which will be passed to <Modal/>

Answer (score 0):

In general this is caused by accidentally adding a non-dom property to a dom element (in this case a div).

If you checkout the spec for div, I suspect that you will not find 'savehere' defined. As such, 'savehere' will have no effect on the div element.

You can see what attributes you can pass to such elements via the mdn pages (linked below but you can just go there and search for them).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/div
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes

As such, it could be argued that this is a mistake on the part of react bootstrap's Modal component which appears to be passing on all props to ModalDialog and somewhere down the line that passes your prop to a .

On you side you can 'fix' this by only passing the props that you wish to give and by reformulating your approach.

The general, and quite clean, practice that seems to be ubiquitous in the React world (pushed by linter defaults, used in example code in docs and guides etc) would be to:

1. refactor this quite simple set of components into functions
2. destructure your props at the component definition
3. pass only the variables you need
4. keep your handlers in the parent

So the parent component would look sth like:

````
const CreateMeeting = ({modalProp1, modalProps2, whatever}) => {
  const [guestModalShow, setGuestModalShow] = useState(false)
  const handleSaveClick = () => {
    console.log('clicked')
  }
  const closeModal = () => setGuestModalShow(false)

  return (
      <Modal
        modalProp1={modalProp1}
        modalProps2={modalProp2}
        size="lg"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
      >
        <Modal.Header >
        <label >Cancel</label>
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter">
            New Meeting
          </Modal.Title>
          <label>Create</label>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
       <label variant="primary" onClick={()=>this.as(true)}>
            Add Guest 
          </label>

        </Modal.Body>
        <Modal.Footer>
          <Button onClick={this.props.onHide}>Close</Button>
        </Modal.Footer>
        <AddGuest
          show={guestModalShow}
          savehere={handleSaveClick}
          onHide={closeModal}
        />
      </Modal>      
    )
    }
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

for react-bootstrap you might still spread out the props ( i'm using functional components, React 18.1.0 and typescript)

```
<CustomModal handleshow={setCustomModalShow}/> <-- from the parentcomponent with customprop (here a ReactSetAction from usestate())
```

custom Modal component:

```
CustomModal = (props:
    JSX.IntrinsicAttributes &
    Omit<Pick<DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>,
        HTMLDivElement>, "key" | keyof HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement>> &
    { ref?: ((instance: HTMLDivElement | null) => void) | 
    RefObject<HTMLDivElement> | null | undefined; },
        BsPrefixProps<"div"> & ModalProps> &
    BsPrefixProps<"div"> &
    ModalProps &
    { children?: ReactNode; }, //all the types from a React-Bootstrap-Modal
    handleshow: (e: boolean) => void // followed by the customprop and its type
    ) => {
         return(
            <Modal {...{ ...props, handleshow: handleshow }} >
            ...modalstuff here
            <Modal/>)
            }
```

and the error from the OP went away (it worked as intended before, yet the error popped up).

Answer (score -1):

**this.asd** this is a function, you don’t need to wrap it in the function again.

```
<AddGuest
     show={this.state.guestModalShow}
     savehere={this.asd}
     onHide={() => this.as(false)}
/>
```